# Why does async routine not return control to the end user

Tags: wpf, vb.net, asynchronous

Working in wpf with mvvm pattern.  I have a area in my application that runs a query against the underlying database which is returned in the form of xml (albeit unformatted at this stage).  I then aim to display this xml in a syntax editor (once it has been correctly formatted) so that it is easier for the end user to read.  Depending upon the date range parameters supplied by the end user for the query the xml returned can run from a few tens of lines to potentially two or three thousand lines which can take some time to format.  A typical returned query of about 350 lines takes about 6 seconds to format.

Because of this potential delay I thought that I would try to use an async routine so that the end user did not think that the application had frozen.  I accept that my knowledge of async is patchy and I've read the help available and followed a couple of walkthroughs to try and at least make a strat in the right direction.

The routine I have below works (in so far as the query is run and eventually we have properly formatted xml appear in the syntax editor).  However it fails in so far as the main intention that control should be handed back to the ui does not appear to happen and the string messages that I'm passing to the status bar (with the exception of the very last one 'Submission Document Completed') aren't being shown either.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing incorrectly here.

Thanks

```
Private Async Sub CreateNewErsBuyersSubmissionByDate(ByVal obj As Object)
        SiAuto.Main.LogMessage("Button Clicked on Ribbon")
        ApplicationStatusLabelText = "Creating Submission Document"
        FormattedString = Await FormatDocument()
        Dim language As New XmlSyntaxLanguage()
        submissionsEditor.Document.Language = language
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(FormattedString) Then
            submissionsEditor.Document.SetText(FormattedString)
            AllowErsSubmissionValidation = True
        Else
            AllowErsSubmissionValidation = False
        End If
        ApplicationStatusLabelText = "Submission Document Completed"
        SiAuto.Main.LogMessage("Routine Finished")
    End Sub

    Public Async Function FormatDocument() As Task(Of String)
        SiAuto.Main.LogMessage("Started to format document")
        Dim xmlValue As String = Await SetupNewErsSubmissionByDateRange()
        Dim language As New XmlSyntaxLanguage()
        Dim doc As New CodeDocument With {.Language = language}
        doc.SetText(xmlHeader & Environment.NewLine & xmlValue)
        Dim textFormatter As ITextFormatter = doc.Language.GetService(Of ITextFormatter)()
        If Not (textFormatter Is Nothing) Then
            ApplicationStatusLabelText = "Formatting Submission Document for display, please wait..."
            textFormatter.Format(doc.CurrentSnapshot.SnapshotRange)
        End If
        SiAuto.Main.LogMessage("Finished formating document")
        Return doc.CurrentSnapshot.Text
    End Function
```

Comment: After Await calls you're directly access wpf control, aren't you? Is 'submissionsEditor' the name of a control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Async` does not mean "execute on a background thread". If you need to push CPU-bound work to a background thread, use `Task.Run`:

```
FormattedString = Await Task.Run(Function() FormatDocument())
```

Note that `FormatDocument` would then run on a background thread, so it can no longer access UI elements (i.e., `ApplicationStatusLabelText`).

Comment: Thank you Stephen, you've provided enough of a clue to help me make progress.